# Multiple polymorphic relationships in Ember (Octane) models and Mirage

Tags: javascript, ember.js, multiple-inheritance, ember-cli-mirage

In our Rails backend, we have a lot of `Concerns` server side. For example, several models import an `AppointableConcern` which allows the resources to be associated with `Appointments`. Each model can import an unlimited number of `Concerns`.

In our Ember Octane models, we use inheritance instead, and I'm not sure whether that's a good idea. For example, we have these two models...

```
// models/groupable.js
import { belongsTo } from '@ember-data/model';
import ApplicationModel from './application'

export default ApplicationModel.extend({
  group: belongsTo('group', { inverse: 'groupables' }),
});

// models/appointable.js
import { hasMany } from '@ember-data/model';
import Groupable from './groupable';

export default Groupable.extend({
  appointments: hasMany('appointment')
});
```

... as well as some models extending either `Appointable` or `Groupable`.

To me it seems inheritance has been abused to share logic between classes that are not closely related: An `Appointable` is not a specific implementation of a `Groupable` (multiple `Groupables` can form a `Group`) at all.

Now I wonder:

- Is this a recommended/standard way to share this logic between models?
- Is there a more flexible alternative? Considering my example above, directly using `group: belongsTo('group', { inverse: 'groupables' })` in any model that should be groupable and `appointments: hasMany('appointment')` in all models that appointments should be allowed to associate with seems like a simple solution.

*edit:*

We encountered a problem with the solution i sketched out above. It is related to EmberCLI Mirage tests: I wanted to make one more model `groupable`, but it does not fit in the inheritance chain well. We couldn't make it inherit from the `Groupable` model. So we added this line directly to the new model: `group: belongsTo('group', { inverse: 'groupables' })`

This works in the browser, but in Mirage I got this error:

```
The 'article' type does not implement 'groupable' and thus cannot be assigned to the 'groupables' relationship in 'group'. Make it a descendant of 'groupable' or use a mixin of the same name.
```

But as there is no multiple inheritance, I can't make `Article` a descendant of `Groupable` and there are no mixins in Mirage at all. So I removed `{ inverse: 'groupables' }` from my new model, which is ok for the moment, but we shouldn't need to take away functionality from our code just to make a test work.

Comment: Ember does a good job of attempting to automatically assume the inverse of a relationship. It could be that explicating the inverse is not needed. I'm not sure functionality is effected by not showing it in this case.